# Pick JSON array object by its key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have JSON array that looks like

```
var data = {
  "fields": [{
      "firstName": {
        "fieldName": "First Name",
        "required": true,
        "provided": false
      }
    },
    {
      "lastName": {
        "fieldName": "Last Name",
        "required": true,
        "provided": false
      }
    },
    {
      "email": {
        "fieldName": "Email",
        "required": true,
        "provided": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Further down I am trying to do this:

1. Access the `fieldName` of the firstName object. Is there to do that without using the index?

`data.fields` gives me the array of object. From there onwards, I do not seem to be able to access with the object key.

Also, `data.fields[0]` gives the whole firstName object but I can't seem to do `data.fields[0]["field"]` or `data.fields[0].field`

Thanks.

Comment: `data.fields gives me the array of object. From there onwards, I do not seem to be able to access with the object key.` - `data.fields[0].firstName.fieldName`

Comment: just a heads up ... there is no JSON in your question **at all**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.find` to find a particular element in an array:

```js
var data={"fields":[{"firstName":{"fieldName":"First Name","required":!0,"provided":!1}},{"lastName":{"fieldName":"Last Name","required":!0,"provided":!1}},{"email":{"fieldName":"Email","required":!0,"provided":!1}}]}
const firstNameFieldName = data.fields
  .find(obj => 'firstName' in obj)
  .firstName.fieldName;
console.log(firstNameFieldName);
```

Also note that you do *not* have a "JSON array". JSON is a *notation* for representing objects as *strings*. You just have a plain *object*.

You might find it easier if you turned the `fields` into an object instead of an array, such as:

```
var data = {
  fields: {
    "firstName": {
      "fieldName": "First Name",
      "required": true,
      "provided": false
    },
    "lastName": {
      "fieldName": "Last Name",
      "required": true,
      "provided": false
    },
    "email": {
      "fieldName": "Email",
      "required": true,
      "provided": false
    }
  }
};
```

Then you could access the properties directly with, for example, `data.fields.firstName` without having to resort to `.find`.

Answer (score 1):

`data.fields[0]` is this object

```
{
    "firstName": {
        "fieldName": "First Name",
        "required": true,
        "provided": false
    }
}
```

So if you want to access anything indide that object which is `firstName` key, you don't need to use index because it is an Object and not an Array. You can access it like `data.fields[0].firstName` which will be equal  to

```
{
    "fieldName": "First Name",
    "required": true,
    "provided": false
}
```

And further if you want to access inner fields/properties, do `data.fields[0].firstName.fieldName` and so on